# icon font doesn't fit to center in big size

Tags: html, css, icon-fonts

I'm using fonttello, but it doesn't scale from center.

my html

```
<span class="icon-marker-dot x2 icon_centering"></span>
```

css

```
.icon_centering {
    font-size: 5.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #428bca;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrG5g/1/), now the whole thing will scale when you change the `font-size`

CSS

```
.icon_centering {
    font-size: 5.5em;
    line-height:2.5em;
    height:2em;
    width:2em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #428bca;
    border-radius: 9999em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: border radius value problem?

Comment: I dont understand the question?

Comment: you did the right thing! thx so much, but I don't get the concept, I want to know what is 'right' in your code :)

Comment: Setting line-height and vertical-align pushes the font character to the center, glad to help :)